# What is the file name that chronicle queue writes to disk and how do we handle the growth of the file as it keeps growing?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

Can we configure the file that the queue writes as rolling and split it?

Tried to run it with high load

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the file path to a directory, not a file. Chronicle Queue
Will create its own files, into that directory, if you have set it up to do daily rolling, (which is the default ) then it will create a new file each day, and write new messages into that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can control when it rolls by time, by setting the RollCycle. You can have files up to 64 TB without a problem for Chronicle Queue, however reducing the roll cycle should keep the files ot a manageable size.